# Custom String class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a 1-2 punch.

1. I'd like to typecast custom strings.
2. Within runtime I'd like to be able to know the type of a string different from a primitive string.

Here's the code:

```
class TZDatabaseName extends String {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    return this;
  }
}

expect(new TZDatabaseName('Asia/Tokyo') instanceof String).toBeTruthy();
expect(new TZDatabaseName('Asia/Tokyo') instanceof TZDatabaseName).toBeTruthy();
expect(new TZDatabaseName('Asia/Tokyo')).toEqual('Asia/Tokyo');
```

I would like all three of the checks below to pass.

I also have been messing with this method of casting strings as well but I have no way of checking in runtime the type of the variable.

```
export abstract class TZDatabaseName extends String {
  public static MAKE(s: string): TZDatabaseName {
    if (!s.match(/^\w+\/\w+$/)) throw new Error('invalid TZDatabaseName');
    return s as any;
  }
  private __TZDatabaseNameFlag;
}
```

Comment: Why subclass String? This seems really odd.

Comment: I want to type a string and I want to distinguish that type between other types.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V that doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a question about jest, specifically?  If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: @jcalz no it is not, those are example assert functions to clearly demonstrate my intention.

Comment: @ThomasReggi Fair enough, how about... ```expect(TZDatabaseName('Asia/Tokyo') == String('Asia/Tokyo')).toEqual(true)```

Comment: Or change last to `expect(new TZDatabaseName('Asia/Tokyo').toString()).toEqual('Asia/Tokyo');`

Comment: Why not just have a custom class with `.toString()` to return the name? It seems like you're really fighting standard JS semantics by trying to do what you want. I'd really recommend against it.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Simply defining a `toString()` method still leads to Typescript errors if you are trying to assign your custom class to a `string` type.
This is a pretty common thing to do in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, ignore my previous comments about the primitive datatype and object being different, I just tested this myself, and all tests pass? ...

```js
class TZDatabaseName extends String {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    return this;
  }
}


describe('TZDatabaseName', function() {
  it('Instance of String', function() {
    expect(new TZDatabaseName('Asia/Tokyo') instanceof String).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Instance of TZDatabaseName', function() {
    expect(new TZDatabaseName('Asia/Tokyo') instanceof TZDatabaseName).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Equal to Primitive Type', function() {
    expect(new TZDatabaseName('Asia/Tokyo')).toEqual('Asia/Tokyo');
  });
});


describe('More TZDatabaseName', function() {
  it('Primitive Instance of TZDatabaseName', function() {
    expect(''
      instanceof TZDatabaseName).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('Primitive Instance of String', function() {
    expect(''
      instanceof String).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('String Instance of TZDatabaseName', function() {
    expect(String('') instanceof TZDatabaseName).toBeFalsy();
  });
});


// Jasmine htmlReporter
(function() {
  var env = jasmine.getEnv();
  env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
  env.execute();
}());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisiting this a couple years later, it seems I just want to do this:

```
class TZDatabaseName extends String {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    if (!s.match(/^\w+\/\w+$/)) {
      throw new Error('invalid TZDatabaseName');
    }
    return this;
  }
}
```